# Why JavaScript Promise Catch isn't fired

Tags: javascript, promise

Here is a JavaScript code with two promises chained. I was wondering why the catch block isn't hit on running the code.

```
function getPromiseResolve(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve('promise resolved')
    })
}

function getPromiseRejected(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        reject('promise rejected')
    })
}

getPromiseResolve()
.then(function(res){
    getPromiseRejected()
})
.then(function(res){
    console.log('response is ', res);
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log('error is ', error);
})
```

Comment: You're missing a `return` in the `.then()` callback.

Comment: you are missing the `return`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must return the `Promise.reject` for the `catch` to handle it.

From MDN:

> The Promise.reject(reason) method **returns** a Promise object that is rejected with the given reason.

```js
Promise.resolve('good')
.then(function(res){
    return Promise.reject('bad')
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log('error is ', error);
})
```

#### Update

```js
function getPromiseResolve(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve('promise resolved')
    })
}

function getPromiseRejected(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        reject('promise rejected')
    })
}

getPromiseResolve()
.then(function(res){
    return getPromiseRejected() // LOOK HERE
})
.then(function(res){
    console.log('response is ', res);
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log('error is ', error);
})
```

Comment: Still need to `return` the result of the function call;

Comment: even if I don't return, the second .then executes. Similarly I expect the catch to work in case of a reject. your thoughts ?

Comment: So you want the second `then` to run even if there is an error? Have you ran the second snippet I added?

Answer (score -1):

```js
Promise.resolve('good')
.then(function(res){
    return Promise.reject('bad')
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log('error is ', error);
})

// OR

Promise.resolve('good')
.then(function(res){
    throw new Error('bad')
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log('error is ', error.message);
})
```